# Best way to get parents and children relationships within one table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

These are my tables:

**User**:

```
id      username        password
1       user1           ********
2       user2           ********
3       user3           ********
4       user4           ********
5       user5           ********
6       user6           ********
```

**UserConnections**:

```
pivot_id    parent_user_id  child_user_id
1           1               2
2           1               3
3           3               4
4           3               5
```

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function connections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserConnections')->with(['parent','child']);
    }
}

class UserConnection extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User','parent_user_id');
    }

    public function child()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User','child_user_id');
    }   
}

$user = App\User::find(3);
```

Now when I call `$user->connections` for user id 3;

It should give me 2,3 & 4 row from the `UserConnections` table

**Explaination**:
In row second, user3 has a parent that is user1
In row third & fourth, user3 has two children

Comment: I think it would be easier and more correct, if you change your UserConnections table and add Connection table.
Connection table - id, type (For example: {[1 => 'parent', 2 => 'child']})

And in UserConnection have who, with whom, what type of connection.

Comment: @Autista_z from your solution, I will have to create two rows for single connection, one for parent and one for child, and I don't want that.

Comment: After thinking on it, I have figured out that your solution is best @Autista_z Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what solved my problem:

**User**:

```
id      username        password
1       user1           ********
2       user2           ********
3       user3           ********
4       user4           ********
5       user5           ********
6       user6           ********
```

**UserConnections**:

```
pivot_id    parent_user_id  child_user_id   relation
1           1               2               child
2           2               1               parent
3           1               3               child
4           3               1               parent
5           3               4               child
6           4               3               parent
7           3               5               child
8           5               3               parent
```

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function connections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Newsroom','UserConnections','parent_user_id','child_user_id')->with(['user']);
    }
}

class UserConnection extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User','child_user_id');
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Autista_z

Comment: I'm glad I helped. This is better sollution for sure. Now you can easily seach a get only parents, childs ...
In your original solution it was a little bit harder.

Comment: @Autista_z Exactly. Thanks again.